# How to get the URL of the actual view from a partial view in the layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I´m trying to dynamically add the class "active" to a nav element in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. After looking through some answers, I got this.

C#:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string IsLinkActive(this UrlHelper url, string action, string controller)
        {
            string currentController = url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            string currentAction = url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

            if (currentController == controller && currentAction == action)
            {
                return "active";
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of the html code:

```
<li class="@Url.IsLinkActive(item.Method, item.Controller)"></li>
```

The problem is that, as the Menu where I'm using the IsLinkActive is on a partial view, called from the layout, the currentController and currentAction variables always returns the partial view route.

The idea is that, if the item method and controller are the same as the actual page, the 'li' element should get the active class.

How can I get the real url values, and not the partial view ones?

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Open the webpage with notepad and see what properties have the full url.

Comment: I use  ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] in my layout page to know which action has been called from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get to the values. For anyone struggling with this, this is my solution:

```
string[] route= url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.FilePath.Split('/');
            string currentController = route[1];
            string currentAction = route[2];
```